# Footer is Overlapping an element, Quick Solution to auto push it down?

Tags: css

I apologize ahead of time, I am not a skilled web designer at all, and I did do some googling before asking this, but it was complicated as most solutions require creating new divs and stuff, I was hoping there is a simple mod or line I could just add to the existing code for the footer to solve this?

Here is the site: http://ratecitident.com/    See how the black footer is overlapping the ratings box, how can I prevent this, to keep the footer at the base on any size screen? it may not show the problem on your screen, but it does on certain sizes, and on phones. 
This is how it looks like on my desktop screen: http://gyazo.com/112b627bb056fc0bc6eb48070939d9b7

Thanks

Comment: add `padding-bottom` to your `#content` div equal to the height (and any margin/spacing) from the `footer`

Comment: this is what happened when I tried that: http://gyazo.com/d61bd609df151a309292c85ff6d3ba57

Comment: you currently have your `footer` element `position:absolute`.. change it to `position:fixed` as well as the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add this little bit of code to your CSS:

```
div#content {
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

This is gonna give you more spacing,because you are forcing the footer to bottom of the content div to `20px`.

You can always,target a specific screen using [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/),in this case you must target the iPhone screen,here is some good tutorials about the media queries.

[css-tricks.com's tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

[mozilla developer network's tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: this is what happened when I tried that: http://gyazo.com/d61bd609df151a309292c85ff6d3ba57

Comment: you have this media query in your css remove it:@media screen and (max-height: 671px)
.index-footer {
position: relative; you must write your css in general,then you have to target any specific screen sizes.
}

Comment: change the footer code to .footer {
position: relative;
bottom: 0;
margin-top: 20px;
width: 100%;
height: 55px;
background: #000;
} you have set a relative positioning for max-height of 671px and absolute for the other screen sizes. that was the cause of the problem change the footer positioning to relative instead.

Comment: omg, I think that worked! Thank you! ...but question, the footer is still not technically attached to the base, right?  because when I view the site on an iphone simulator, there is a big white gap at the bottom: http://mobiletest.me/iphone_5_emulator/#u=http://ratecitident.com/

Comment: that's because of the iPhone height,you can change the footer height to 77px or margin size to 40px using media queries to target the iPhone